# Nokia's Here Batch Geocoding REST request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, http-post, here-api

I'm trying to perform a post request to the Batch Geocoding in NodeJS.
I'm using Request library but since the post data is required to be sent as multiline column plain text data, the request fails.

Sample post data (with column delimiter '|'):

```
recId|searchText|country
0001|Invalidenstraße 116 10115
```

Here's my request:

```
requestPromise.post({
        uri: 'https://batch.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/jobs',
        qs: {
            app_id: {APP ID}
            , app_code: {APP CODE}
            , action: 'run'
            , mailto: {EMAIL}
            , gen: 8
            , header: true
            , ndelim: '%7C'
            , outdelim: '%7C'
            , outcols: 'displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country'
            , outputCombined: false
        },
        body:'recId|searchText|country\r\n0001|Invalidenstraße 116 10115 Berlin|DEU',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'text/plain',
        }
```

Note this part, I tried using newline chars (\r\n):

```
body:'recId|searchText|country\r\n0001|Invalidenstraße 116 10115 Berlin|DEU'
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> Invalid input header(s) detected: [recId|searchText|country]. Please fix the input or check the input delimiter setting.

Comment: use backticks ( string template/literals  )instead of single quotes, remove `\r\n` and  hit the enter key at that point

Answer (score 0):

Belleive you have a typo on indelim parameter.

Comment: did that fixed the issue :-)